# Closure linter warning about interfaces

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-linter

I'm using the closure compiler and I have two classes that I would like to assert have a minimum set of methods/properties.  To accomplish this, I've created an interface ... e.g.:

```
goog.scope(function() {



/**
 * @interface
 */
namespace.Foo = function() {};
var Foo = namespace.Foo


/**
 * @return {string}
 */
Foo.prototype.bar = function() {};

});  // goog.scope
```

The problem is that `Foo.prototype.bar` doesn't have a `return` statement, so the closure linter complains even though closure itself is completely happy.

```
Line 38, E:0218: Found @return JsDoc on function that returns nothing
Line 56, E:0218: Found @return JsDoc on function that returns nothing
```

Of course, if I remove the `@return` annotations then closure is unhappy and throws warnings about overriding a method and returning something incompatible with the interface.  I don't want to disable this warning because that's pretty much the reason why I wrote the interface in the first place (to make sure that all of the implementors are doing what they need to do).

Is there any magical incantation that I can use to disable that warning in the closure linter just in this file?

Comment: It might be a bit weird that linter and compiler disagree, but the main question should be: Why did you implement a method that has to return a string but does not?

Comment: @Bergi -- That's what interfaces are used for.  In fact, if you try to put something in an interface, closure will yell at you.  Basically an interface (or a record with different amounts of type checking) describes an object that can be passed around to different methods, but it is up to the programmer to create a concrete implementation that satisfies the interface.

Comment: Yeah, sure. I guess I'm just not familiar enough with closure compiler, this interface *declaration* looks too much like an implementation to me… (and maybe to the linter as well).

Comment: @Bergi -- Yeah it does look like an actual implementation.  I guess they're liimited since they have to build all the pieces from valid javascript so that it can run with or without compiling.

Comment: Hello @mgilson, wondering if you feel your question has been answered? If so perhaps you can mark one of the answers as "the answer". :)

Comment: @owler -- The question has been answered for me.  I've been having a hard time choosing between your answer and mine.  I had hoped that the community would vote more and make my decision easier -- Because I don't know which is more correct.  Unfortunately, with only 23 views, it's hard to say which is more correct... :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
/**
 * @return {string}
 */
namespace.Foo.prototype.bar;
```

Interfaces don't need any function body at all.  I suspect they are only visible to the compiler and don't even wind up in your code at all.

Or, because you are using `goog.scope` you can write:

```
/**
 * @return {string}
 */
Foo.prototype.bar;
```

Comment: You're right, this seems to work, both for the compiler and for the linter.  I like that it lets me cut out the namespace (when used in conjunction with `goog.scope`), but I like how the original makes it more clear that `bar` is a method and not a property.  I suppose this is a case of not being able to have the cake and eat it too :-)

Comment: The documentation for a method in an interface will have things like `@param` and `@return`.  I don't even know how to specify a property in an interface, I think I've only ever had methods.  There are several other tags like `@dict, @enum, @record, @struct` which might be what you want instead of `@interface`.  See https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#tags

Comment: the documentation you link says "Any class that implements an interface must implement all of the methods and properties defined on the interface's prototype", so I think that it's possible.  I'm also aware of the annotations you mention, but they don't satisfy my use-case.  We have an angular app and are serving a template for a modal.  That modal is used in different places, but unfortunately, it was pretty hard to share the controllers so I wanted to make sure that all of the controllers implemented the methods and properties that the modal requires (hence the interface).

Comment: Oh, and specifying properties on interfaces works the same as methods -- you just don't add `@param` or `@return` annotations ;-).

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the answer was just waiting to be discovered in the closure-linter [source code/test cases](https://github.com/google/closure-linter/blob/master/closure_linter/testdata/interface.js):

They write something like:

```
/**
 * Sample interface to demonstrate correct style.
 * @interface
 */
sample.GoodInterface = function() {
};


/**
 * Legal methods can take parameters and have a return type.
 * @param {string} param1 First parameter.
 * @param {Object} param2 Second parameter.
 * @return {number} Some return value.
 */
sample.GoodInterface.prototype.legalMethod = function(param1, param2) {
};
```

which apparently lints fine in their test cases.  How is that different from mine?  Well, they didn't use `goog.scope` to do any aliasing.  When I removed the aliasing (e.g.

```
/**
 * @return {string}
 */
namespace.Foo.prototype.bar = function() {};
```

the closure-linter is now smart enough to figure out that `Foo` is part of an interface and it doesn't require any implementation in the methods.  Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [@abstract](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-abstract.html) tag, this may help. If not, closure complier can [suppress](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Warnings#suppress-tags) warnings. I think something like this will work.

```
/**
 * @return {string}
 * @suppress {missingReturn}
 */
 Foo.prototype.bar = function() {};
```

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to not work.  Closure already knows that the missing return is OK, and the closure-linter doesn't seem to pick up on the intent of the `@suppress`.